# Show H3 heading above button

Tags: javascript

This code works well but the problem is that I wanna show text with h3 heading above the button.

```
<script>
    let button = document.getElementById("btn");
    let body = document.getElementById("main");
    let colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "purple", "skyblue", "orange", "pink"];

    function changeColor() {
        let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
        body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "<h3> Color </h3> " + colors[i];

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн sure here is demo of my code [link](https://codepen.io/akashjangra89/pen/GRpNqRx)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question what is your markup but I suppose it looks something like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="para"></div>
    <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

In this case, your js should be:

```
let button = document.getElementById("btn");
let body = document.getElementById("main");
let para = document.getElementById("para");
let colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "purple", "skyblue", "orange", "pink"];

function changeColor() {
    let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    para.innerHTML = `<h3> ${colors[i]} </h3>`;
} 

button.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```

Notice you have to add an EventListener on your button in order for it to invoke `changeColor`. Alternatively, you can use `onclick` on the button element.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a css related issue. To fix this, you just need to wrap `para` and `btn` elements inside another div like:

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="row">
    <p id="para"></p>
    <button id="btn" onclick="changeColor()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then add some css styling for `para`, so that there some gap between the button and the h3 heading like:

```
#para {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Demo:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("btn");
let body = document.getElementById("main");
let colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "purple", "skyblue", "orange", "pink"];

function changeColor() {
  let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "<h3> Color </h3> " + colors[i];
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#para {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#btn {
  padding: 12px 18px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 10px 5px gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#btn:hover {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="row">
    <p id="para"></p>
    <button id="btn" onclick="changeColor()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```